# Use environment variable as compile time constant in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, environment-variables

As part of a build process, I need to take an environment variable defined by a batch script and use it as a constant within the code at compile time.

For example, say I have defined an environment variable named `BUILD_VERSION` and set it to `1.0.0`, when compiled I want `1.0.0` to be baked into my code. EG:

Batch file:

```
set BUILD_VERSION = 1.0.0
; call vs compiler
```

C++ File:

```
const std::string build_version = BUILD_VERSION // Which will result in "1.0.0".
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: would the /DBUILD_VERSION="1.0.0" not work?

Comment: That's probably exactly what I'm after. Will try it now.

Comment: Note that depending on how you define it too you might need to stringize the macro (i.e. `build_version = #BUILD_VERSION`)

Comment: Super! That worked a treat. Can you answer the question so I can accept? :)

Comment: I would accept your answer; you have a pic, I was just going to put some text ;) But I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end I followed [txchelp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152524/txtechhelp) advice and added a `/D` flag into the *Command Line -> Additional Options* section of the project properties to declare the environment variable as a preprocessor definition.

It looked something like this:

[image]

Then in the batch script that started the build:

```
set SVN_BUILD_VERSION=1.0.0
```

And finally to extract it as a string within the source code:

```
#define STRINGIZER(arg)     #arg
#define STR_VALUE(arg)      STRINGIZER(arg)
#define BUILD_VERSION_STRING STR_VALUE(BUILD_VERSION)

// ...

const std::string version = BUILD_VERSION_STRING; // Results in "1.0.0".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prebuild step (I suppose you are on Visual Studio) which will run script which will get this environment variable value, parse C++ source file and change the value 
"1.0.0.0" to "1.0.0.1".

Such substitution can be conveniently done by [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Answer (score 0):

A [`VERSION_INFO` resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could be a good way go.

The version info so embedded can be inspected by right-clicking the executable and checking its properties.

To do that at the command line:

- Redirect output from a batch file to an [.rc] file defining the resource.
- Compile the resource using `rc.exe`.
- Embed the resulting `.res` file by simply passing it to the linker.

Within Visual Studio it might be more complicated.