# How can I use environment variable as compile-time constant in native nodejs addon?

Tags: c++, node.js, environment-variables, node-gyp

I am writing a native addon for NodeJS. How can I use an environment variable as a constant at compile time? That is, "inject" a constant in to the NodeJS C++ addon from an environment variable set during `node-gyp build` or `npm install`. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826665/use-environment-variable-as-compile-time-constant-in-c), however as far as I can see, there is no equivalent option for passing through variables to node-gyp

Comment: You can't. Variables aren't constant. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP I wasn't asking how to make a variable constant (definitely a contradiction in terms), I'm asking how to define a constant at compile time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that the `defines` block and variable expansion in binding.gyp will achieve what I'm after:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "targetName",
      "sources": [ "source.cc" ],
      "defines": [
        'MY_DEFINE="<!(echo $MY_ENV_VAR)"'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then `MY_DEFINE` is available with value equal to whatever `MY_ENV_VAR` set set to at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you create a Makefile yourself you can pass options to the compiler like:

```
-D name=definition
```

which is equivalent of having this in the source code:

```
#define name "definition"
```

so using:

```
-D NAME=$NAME
```

would put the `NAME` environment variable as a `NAME` constant in the compiled source code.

But with `node-gyp` the Makefile is generated for you, see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

You may need to change the generated Makefile after you run:

```
node-gyp configure
```

but before you run:

```
node-gyp build
```

or you can make a simple library which entire purpose would be to have a given value defined that would be used by your Node addon.

Another option would be to have a script that does something like:

```
echo "#define NAME \"$NAME\"" > config.h
```

and you can then include the `config.h` file by your Node native addon or any other code written in C or C++.